# Movable dynamic Bootstrap Tab menu slider if limit reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have dynamic tabs menu in my website, a tabs menu item may be 2 or 3 and may be 20+.
So when navigation item is more than 10+ is automatically drop to second line see [here](http://www.bootply.com/ifkjE1wdCU).

I don't want this effect, i want if navigation limit reached so next arrow icon appear and by clicking on it the remaining menu item will move left.

i tried following but not get success.

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab1 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab2 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab3 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab4 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab5 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab6 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab7 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab8 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab9 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab10 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab11 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab12 example</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button id="goPrev">Prev</button>
<button id="goNext">Next</button>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width:1000px;
  background: #dad9d9;
    border: 1px solid #efefef;
}

.wrap>.nav-tabs {
  display: inline-block;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.wrap>.nav-tabs>li {
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  white-space: normal;
  float: none;
}
.nav-tabs>li>a {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

JavaScript/JQuery

```
var wrap = $(".wrap").width();
var el = $("ul").width();
if (el > wrap) {
  $("#goNext").click(function() {
    $("ul").stop(true);
    if (-parseInt($("ul").css("left")) - wrap < 0) {
      $("ul").animate({
        "left": "+=-" + wrap
      }, "slow")
    } else {
      $("ul").animate({
        "left": "-" + (el - wrap)
      }, "slow")
    }

  });
  $("#goPrev").click(function() {
    $("ul").stop(true);
    if (-parseInt($("ul").css("left")) - wrap > 0) {
      $("ul").animate({
        "left": "+=" + wrap
      }, "slow")
    } else {
      $("ul").animate({
        "left": "0"
      }, "slow")
    }

  });
}
```

[**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/jtxKBfZc3L)

**Note:** I don't want to use any plugin for this small thing also make sure the slider should be Responsive.

Thanks

Comment: What you are looking for is a slider of menu items right? Have a look at http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/custom.html

Comment: i don't want to use whole plugin just for this small feature

Comment: Your `bootply demo` is working fine according to your question, what else do you want ?

Comment: its not working according to my expectation try to click next btn check the silly behavior :(

Comment: So you are using bootstarp ? While you set wrap'width 1000px, does "when navigation item is more than 10+ is automatically drop to second line" mean each menu' width is 100px  ?

Comment: @TTCC yes i am using bootstrap , No wrap width is 100% see my updated link  http://www.bootply.com/jtxKBfZc3L and no each item has auto width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the fix width by calculating each item. Its working perfect now.

```js
function itemWidth() {
  // get the larger item to set the width of every item
  var largestWidth = 0;
  $(".nav-tabs>li>a").each(function() {
    if ($(this).outerWidth() > largestWidth) {
      largestWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
    }
  });
  Wrap = $(".wrap").outerWidth(); // the wrapper full width
  someSpace = largestWidth + 10; // make some space, 5px each side
  roundFigure = Wrap / someSpace; // parent width divided by larger item width
  roundFigure = Math.round(roundFigure); // round the figure 
  finalWidth = Wrap / roundFigure; // get the final width 
  $(".nav-tabs>li>a").outerWidth(finalWidth); // set the final width
}

itemWidth(); // call the funcation

// do the magic
var menus = $("#menus"),
  menuWidth = menus.parent().outerWidth();
var menupage = Math.ceil(menus[0].scrollWidth / menuWidth),
  currPage = 1;
if (menupage > 1) {
  $("#goNext").click(function() {
    currPage < menupage && menus.stop(true).animate({
      "left": -menuWidth * currPage
    }, "slow") && currPage++
  });
  $("#goPrev").click(function() {
    currPage > 1 && menus.stop(true).animate({
      "left": -menuWidth * (currPage - 2)
    }, "slow") && currPage--;
  });
  // refresh on resize 
  $(window).on("resize", function() {
   itemWidth();
    menuWidth = menus.parent().outerWidth();
    menupage = Math.ceil(menus[0].scrollWidth / menuWidth);
    currPage = Math.ceil(-parseInt(menus.css("left")) / menuWidth) + 1;
  });
}
```

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
.tab-slider {
  padding: 0 40px;
}

.tab-slider .btn-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
}

#goPrev {
  left: 0;
}

#goNext {
  right: 0;
}

.wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  background: #dad9d9;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  font-size: 0;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.nav-tabs>li.active>a,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.wrap>.nav-tabs {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.wrap>.nav-tabs>li {
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  white-space: normal;
  float: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a {
  margin-right: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-slider">
  <div class="wrap">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="menus">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab1 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab2 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab3 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab4 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab5 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab6 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab7 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab8 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab9 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab10 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab11 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab13 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab14 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab15 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab16 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab17 example</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <button id="goPrev" class="btn btn-default btn-icon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></button>
  <button id="goNext" class="btn btn-default btn-icon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just define a globle "currPage" variable. Try this ( See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ttccmvp/taLfope4/)):

```js
var menus = $("#menus"), menuWidth = menus.parent().outerWidth();
    var menupage = Math.ceil(menus[0].scrollWidth / menuWidth), currPage = 1;
    if (menupage > 1) {
        $("#goNext").click(function () {
            currPage < menupage && menus.stop(true).animate({
                "left": -menuWidth * currPage
            }, "slow") && currPage++
        });
        $("#goPrev").click(function () {
            currPage > 1 && menus.stop(true).animate({
                "left": -menuWidth * (currPage - 2)
            }, "slow") && currPage--;
        });
        $(window).on("resize", function () {
            menuWidth = menus.parent().outerWidth();
            menupage = Math.ceil(menus[0].scrollWidth / menuWidth);
            currPage = Math.ceil(-parseInt(menus.css("left")) / menuWidth) + 1;
        });
    }
```

```css
/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.tab-slider {
  padding:0 40px;
}
.tab-slider .btn-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
}
#goPrev {
  left:0;
}
#goNext {
  right:0;
}
.wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  background: #dad9d9;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  font-size: 0;
}

.nav-tabs>li.active>a,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.wrap>.nav-tabs {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.wrap>.nav-tabs>li {
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  white-space: normal;
  float: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a {
  margin-right: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-slider">
  <div class="wrap">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="menus">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab1 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab2 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab3 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab4 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab5 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab6 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab7 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab8 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab9 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab10 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab11 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab13 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab14 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab15 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab16 example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab17 example</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <button id="goPrev" class="btn btn-default btn-icon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></button>
  <button id="goNext" class="btn btn-default btn-icon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button>
</div>
```

Note: I add a id `menus` to your `<ul class="nav nav-tabs">`

Comment: i tested your code its not working properly when i resize browser to small size

Comment: I will post a jsfiddle later.

Comment: i just see your updated answer but still has an issue while resizing

Comment: Sorry, I omit a minus

Comment: have u updated the link ? if yes,  still the same issue

Comment: So, what's the  problem in more detail?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118228/discussion-between-ttcc-and-ismail-farooq).

Answer (score 0):

If you set a very large width on the UL `<ul class="nav nav-tabs">` the tabs will display in one long line.

You would probably need some JS to check the window width and the width of the total tabs to see if you need to display your arrow or not.

The arrows could then trigger some JS to move the UL to show the other tabs.

**Update:** 
See example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hq0189rd/

Comment: the question still remain same, HOW ? i need example

Comment: Take a look at the JS fiddle I have added. This does what you need.

Comment: see the above answer its almost correct it have just one problem the menu button cuts the last/first item when slides

Comment: I have answered your question. The answer below is also correct. If you want someone to actually build a production ready page for you then I'll send you my freelance prices ;)